# Preencher um association apartir de outro - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocompletar

Tenho uma aplicação para agenda de serviços e não estou conseguindo preencer um selectbox apartir da seleção feita em outro. Explicando melhor:
Tenho um selectbox com os serviços disponiveis e qdo seleciono um serviço, quero preencher o selectbox dos profissionais que tenham a mesma especialidade do serviço selecionado. Na classe de profissionais tenho:

class Profissional < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :especialidade
  has_many :reservas...

na classe Serviço:
    class Servico < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :especialidade
  has_many :reservas

na classe Reserva:

```
class Reserva < ActiveRecord::Base
```

belongs_to :cliente
  belongs_to :servico
  belongs_to :profissional

e na view de nova reserva:

```
<%= simple_form_for @reserva, html: { multipart: true,
                                   class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

<%= f.association :cliente, label: 'Cliente:', label_method: :nome,
                      value_method: :id %>
    <%= f.association :servico, label: 'Serviço:', label_method: :nome,
                      value_method: :id %>
    <%= f.association :profissional, label: 'Profissional:',
                      label_method: :nome, value_method: :id %>
    <%= f.input :preco, label: 'Preço:', readonly: true %>

A minha ideia é, ao selecionar o serviço, listar os profissionais com a mesma especialidade e preencher o campo preço que tem no serviço. Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, vamos aos poucos. Primeiro, na model de Profissional acho que o mais certo seria que o Profissional tenha vários ou uma(has_many ou has_one) especialidade(s) e não que pertença a uma especialidade.

Enquanto a sua questão, entendi que após eu selecionar os checkboxs meu sistema procuraria os profissionais que tem aquela habilidade, certo? Para isso te recomendo usar uma gem de busca, como o PGSearch ou outras, dependendo do teu banco.

https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search

Sua model de profissional ficaria:

```
class Profissional < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch

  has_many(has/one) :especialidades
  has_many :reservas

  pg_search_scope :search, against: [:name, :telephone(campos_do_seu_profissional)], :associated_against => {
    :habilidade => [:nome],
  }
end
```

Agora se eu utilizar o método Profissional.search("Mecânico"), se houver algum profissional que tenha a habilidade mecânico, irá retorar pra você neste ActiveRecord.

Espero ter ajudado :)